# How to modify/customise reftex-cite-format

Tags: citing, reftex

Using `reftex-cite-format 'natbib`, one of the default options under `reftex-citation` is `\citep[e.g.][]{%l}`. How can I modify this slightly, to `\citep[e.g.,][]{%l}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you customize several of the entries, you may want to define a variable, say `my-reftex-cite-format` using `reftex-cite-format-builtin` `natbib` entry as starting point. And then set `(setq reftex-cite-format 'my-reftex-cite-format)`.

But if you just want to change this one, you can try:

```lisp
(setf (cdr (assoc ?e (caddr (assoc 'natbib reftex-cite-format-builtin))))
      "\\citep[e.g.,][]{%l}")
```

Somewhat roundabout, true, but this variable is quite nested.

Edit: As requested in the comments, an example of setting `reftex-cite-format` directly (this is what I actually use for `biblatex`).

```lisp
(defvar my/reftex-cite-format-biblatex
  '((?\C-m . "\\cite[][]{%l}")
    (?C    . "\\cites[][]{%l}")
    (?t    . "\\textcite[][]{%l}")
    (?T    . "\\textcites[][]{%l}")
    (?p    . "\\parencite[][]{%l}")
    (?P    . "\\parencites[][]{%l}")
    (?f    . "\\footcite[][]{%l}")
    (?F    . "\\footcites[][]{%l}")
    (?s    . "\\shortcite[][]{%l}")
    (?S    . "\\shortcites[][]{%l}")
    (?a    . "\\citeauthor{%l}")
    (?A    . "\\citeauthor*{%l}")
    (?u    . "\\autocite[][]{%l}")
    (?U    . "\\autocite*[][]{%l}")
    (?i    . "\\citetitle{%l}")
    (?I    . "\\citetitle*{%l}")
    (?y    . "\\citeyear{%l}")
    (?Y    . "\\citeyear*{%l}")
    (?n    . "\\nocite{%l}"))
  "My personal set of biblatex citation commands for use with RefTeX.
Based on the biblatex set of `reftex-cite-format-builtin'.")

(setq reftex-cite-format my/reftex-cite-format-biblatex)
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you provide an example of how to define such a custom `my-reftex-cite-format` variable exactly?

Comment: @lab There you have it.

Comment: Thanks @ArashEsbati, I was wondering why the syntax highlighting was not working...

Comment: @gusbrs - Sure, welcome.  Check this page for a list of [supported languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md).